# In which cases should one use the Navier-Stokes equations for modelling of incompresible fluid dynamics?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation, navier-stokes

I have been doing some exercises in incompressible fluid dynamics, particularly with Navier-Stokes equations, and realized there was an exercise that involved a tubular pipe, that could use preservation of flow equation ($A_1v_1=A_2v_2$) to be solved. However, I'd like to know if I could be on the clear by not choosing to solve the extremely complex navier-stokes equation with continuity equation. I attempted it with Navier-Stokes first but got stuck in trying to obtain a pressure function, then I remembered most of the exercises that needed Navier-Stokes either gave me the pressure gradient or boundary conditions that reduced the amount of variables greatly. So I'd like to know when is it reasonable to use flow conservation equation, and when is it reasonable to use Navier-Stokes.

Comment: Give more details - what exactly is the problem, what is your train of thought in solving it, where did you get stuck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.